# I need to write a Python program using only find() command in files to print all those line which has Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need do to print all that lines in which python appears using find() command in a file. Using python.

these are my file content

```
python is fun
python java 
sai python
sachin
ganesha
```

currently its printing first 2 lines only

What I have tried:

```
fhand=open('demo.txt')
for line in fhand:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if(line.find('python')):
        continue
    print(line)
```

Comment: `line.find('python')` returns `-1` when not found. You need `line.find('python') != -1`

Comment: just a little fyi, opening files is usually better done with 'with' (with open(file, 'r') as f:), since you don't need to worry about closing the file.

Answer (score 2):

`find` returns the position of the string or `-1` if not found, so:

```
line.find('python')
```

will always return a non-zero unless the line *starts* by `python`, and you'll enter the *if*. So every line is skipped except the ones that start with `python` (your first 2 lines match)

You need:

```
if line.find('python') == -1:   # != -1: the string is there
    # python is not in the line
    continue
```

but it's *much* better to just write:

```
if "python" not in line:
   # python is not in the line
   continue
```

since you don't need to know *where* is python located in the line.

Also: perform the `rstrip()` operation only if you need to print the line. Else it just wastes CPU since the result of `find` doesn't depend on it.

So to sum it up here's how I would write it:

```
with open('demo.txt') as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        if "python" in line:            
           print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: Just out of interest, is there a reason you check for "not" instead of checking for python in line?

Comment: the `continue` statement makes the program skip the line. It's inverted logic.